# Objective C: How to store static data to Core Data when application launches

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, static

I am intending to use Core Data to store a static list of data which consist of objects with attributes (e.g. object = person, attributes = weight, height etc).

Any advise on what is the best way to approach this? What raw file format should I need to use and what is the best way to load the data from the raw file to core data?

Appreciate any advise and help on this

Comment: Does the data need to be encrypted for security reasons (for example, does it contain cheats for in your game or something...)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the data set is large, you should include a prepopulated SQLite store in the app bundle.

Create a separate project in Xcode and import the data model and NSManagedObject subclass files (if any.) Write code to import or create the static data and write it all to the persistent store.

Copy/add the persistent store file to the release project. In the release project, set the store pathway to the location of the store file in the app bundle using `[NSBundle pathForResourse:Type]`. In the persistent store options, mark the store as `readonly`.

That will let you set up a prepopulated, readonly Core Data stack that will efficiently handle thousands of objects for you.

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest shipping binary .plist file with initial data and on first launch dump it to CoreData.

Also may I suggest you not use CoreData if your list is going to be immutable. Just read the plist on app startup and keep it in some AppDelegate's instance var.

**Update (to reflect comment):**
If it's a few thousand records - you SHOULD import it to core data as it would improve the performance of data retreval. Also - I would not suggest keeping ALL of them in the memory.

To get data into plist you could use some other programming language to select all the data from database and export it to xml plist (there are libraries for virtually any programming language). Then by using property list editor you would be able to export it to binary plist.

Then depending on what you need to do with your data - you can import it either in background or just show a progress indicator/bar to the user while using main thread for import. I believe plist would take few MB's. Also - try benchmarking a thousand records just to get approximate estimate of how long data import would take.

Comment: thanks for the advice. Can I check why you would not suggest using Core Data? Also if I have a few thousand objects, what is the fastest way to import them into a plist?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend a plist for "thousands of records". As a plist has to be read entirely into memory to be used, a large plist can completely choke an app. A prepopulated SQLite Core Data persistent store is a better option.

Answer (score 0):

1, **You could fill in core data on startup from external source.** On startup, read data from external source(SQLite database or XML file), then insert the data into core data;

2, **Provide pre-filled in SQLite database.** For this we’ll let Core Data create the database structure for us based on the model, and then we populate the database with a utility app. The utility app could be a Mac or iPhone app that uses Core Data to populate the database via Core Data APIs, or some kind of program that fills in the SQLite database directly. Once the database is populated, just include it with the app and make the app use it as the default database if no database already exists.

Hope [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12170/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data-updated) will help.